# Using a Teflon bushing as a roller

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bearings

I have a situation where a 5mm steel rod needs to be in contact and rolls over segments of a 80mm steel pipe's inner face. Would it be a good idea to loosely slip a Teflon bushing over the rod and use it as a roller? I haven't seen loose fitted bushings, so I'm not sure if it'd be right to let a bushing rotate like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine in principal, there are a few applications where a similar arrangement is used, in fact it is common for nylon wheeled castors to just have a plain bore.

In this situation the bushing will tend to travel along the rod as it rotates unless it is constrained so you will need something to locate it axially.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of using a cotter pin on each end. Would the cotter pin wear out the bushing? Should (metal?) washers be used in between? Actually, how about nylon rather than Teflon since you mentioned it?

Comment: Yes cotter pins or circlips with washers should do the job.

Comment: I see. Is nylon supposed to be more durable than Teflon? Maybe I should go for nylon if it were to rub against metal washers axially since thats the material casters use?

Comment: Nylon is a bit more mechanically tough and will tend to be the default choice for wheels and rollers. Teflon is often selected for its very low coefficient of friction and chemical resistance. There are lots of different varieties of both with specific suitabilities.